# Blank page with php artisan serve for laravel 5 in mamp php 5.4.10

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to install Laravel for first time. I installed it on my desktop with the following composer command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-app
```

The command completed successfully without any error but with some messages like

```
symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
```

I now did `chmod -R 777 larvel-app` to make whole folder writable by everyone. I now started php server with following command

```
cd laravel-app
php artisan serve
```

and it gave following message

```
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
```

When viewed from web browser in address http://localhost:8000, there is nothing, only blank page. **When I browse this address, the server seems to quit.**

I have following environment: 
OSX Mavericks;
MAMP with php 5.4.10 and apache2;
following extensions in php.ini file

```
extension=imap.so
extension=yaz.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
;;;;;Following are added by me ;;;;no error when starting server
extension=openssl.so
extension=mbstring.so
```

When I run `which php` from command line, I get following.

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php
```

When I tried to run this in mamp ie localhost:8888, it gave 500 internal server error.

Please suggest me, where I might have made mistake.

Comment: As a Mac user, i really recommend you to use homestead.

Answer (score 1):

As a OSX user i strongly recommend you to use Laravel Homestead to develop your applications.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead

You only need to install:

- Virtualbox
- Vagrant

I have my projects in ~/code folder, so everytime i create a new project, i just:

- Add project test domain to my local host file (my-project.app pointing to localhost 127.0.0.1)
- ssh into the homestead virtualmachine (homestead ssh)
- run built in serve command (serve my-project.app /path/to/project/public)
- Voilà

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for this is that the web server process does not have write access to the `storage` folder and its subfolders.

Set the permissions on the storage folder so that the web server can create files.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use php serve, mamp does that for you. Make sure you point your directory to public folder. You can also use custom domain for each of your projects.

Also for Mac there is laravel valet. Easy to get started with many php projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move your Laravel Application to

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/
```

and then you can access it on

```
http://localhost:8888/laravel-app
```

Comment: Then please look in the error log.

`/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log`

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilterIterator in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-app/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 15267

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/7429 
This error has been fixed 4 days ago, try to update.
Remove your Laravel Application then run 
`composer self-update` and `composer update`.

Then try it again with
`composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-app`

Comment: Similar problem reported after implementing your suggestion

Comment: Do we need to change url in config/app.php?

Comment: You can change it, but it's for artisan commands. But first try to repeat the installation but this time with `composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-app --prefer-dist`